# Set cell value using PHPExcel and setCellValue method

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to set|persist some values in a Excel (.xlsx) file and I'm using `phpoffice/phpexcel` library. This is how my code looks:

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$cRow, $hcpId); // set column A - HCP.ID - value
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$cRow, $terrID); // set column B - TERRITORY.ID - value
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$cRow, $isMatch); // set column C - isMatch TERR_HCP_XREF - value

echo "HCP.ID A{$cRow} => {$hcpId}, TERRITORY.ID B{$cRow} => {$terrID}, isMatch TERR_HCP_XREF {$isMatch} ", EOL;
```

And this is the result on the `echo` sentence:

```
14:44:46 Load from Excel QXR_2015_Q3_PFE_V8_FINAL.xlsx file
HCP.ID A2 => 139810, TERRITORY.ID B2 => 453, isMatch TERR_HCP_XREF FALSE
HCP.ID A3 => 139810, TERRITORY.ID B3 => 560, isMatch TERR_HCP_XREF FALSE
HCP.ID A4 => 135453, TERRITORY.ID B4 => 442, isMatch TERR_HCP_XREF FALSE
HCP.ID A5 => 115075, TERRITORY.ID B5 => 445, isMatch TERR_HCP_XREF TRUE
Call time to read Workbook was 59.0086 seconds
14:45:45 Current memory usage: 409.5 MB
```

But is not working since columns hasn't values after run the script, why? What's wrong in my code? Did I miss something here?

Comment: What Writer are you using?

Comment: And if you're doing `$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();`, then you don't need to do `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(...)` for every cell, but can do `$objWorksheet()->setCellValue(...)` which will be slightly faster

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not using any Writer, do I need it? Can you post an example of what is missing on my code?

Comment: Not using a Writer is like editing a file in MS Excel, but just exiting without saving it.... the Writer is what saves your file

Comment: @MarkBaker can you answer my question by leaving an example or just tell me here to found this on docs?

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok, I just found it on docs but if you like feel free to answer and I give you the points because you help me to find where my mistake was, thanks