# Export XLS file using PHP which limits cell inputs

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to export data in xls file, i have done this and give this excel file to my client for further modifications.

But what i wants in advance is; this modifications should be restricted like:

**`Department`** column's value must be selected from list(this list is dynamically generated from database.table_department ).

**`Product_ID`** column's value must be selected from available distinct products_id from database.table_products

I wants validations something like here mention  [Restrict data to predefined items in a list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-f809371b-214e-4e45-b4b0-f010b1159828)

This validations are applied because this file taken as input for data Import in Admin panel and database have certains PK-FK relationships. In order to remove any discrepancy during data import due to PK-FK relationships this validation is applied for precautions.

Comment: So have you actually looked at any of the libraries like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) (which you've tagged) that can be used to create Excel files? If so, what problems are you having?

Comment: Open-ended "How to" questions are difficult to answer, and tend to generate follow-up discussions. To improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, [edit] your question to provide greater focus on the specific problem you're facing. See [ask].

Comment: @Mark Baker I have looked this post [Set cell value using PHPExcel and setCellValue method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864153/set-cell-value-using-phpexcel-and-setcellvalue-method) and [PHPExcel write from template file, and maintain drop down and validation checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835155/phpexcel-write-from-template-file-and-maintain-drop-down-and-validation-checks)

Comment: And your problem is? Have you tried writing any code? Does it work or not? Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes i had try to implement as above post. but there is no option for List validation